# UITableViewController init vs. initWithStyle

Tags: objective-c, ios

the class ref says:

*If you use the standard init method to initialize a UITableViewController object, a table view in the plain style is created.*

i do not understand, where this behaviour comes from - i would like to see i in some code
or api but

- UITableViewController has no init in its api
- how could some base class' init know about a suitable default style for a derived class?

**thanks for every hint**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every object has an `init` method, but a lot of classes have a so-called *designated* initializer. That is the main initializer, and the others are merely convenience methods calling that designated initializer.

According to that doc, in this case the `init` method probably looks something like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
}
```

Methods from a superclass do not appear in the documentation of the derived class, except if the derived class overrides it and has something important to say about it. That's why you don't see `init` documented in `UITableViewController`, it's part of `NSObject` from which UITableViewController derives (through UIScrollView -> UIView -> UIResponder -> NSObject).

As for the second part of your question: a base class can (should) never know anything about derived classes. A derived class that wants a different default style simple overrides `init` again.

Comment: then i would prefer having init in the doc because it has something important to say (being different from NSObject's) - instead of putting it in some mystic discussion comment !? thanx anyway:-)

Answer (score 2):

in UITableViewController.m

```
- (id) init 
{
   return [self initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
}
```

The `init` method will call the designated initializer.

Comment: but this implementation is not available, so i really would prefer init in the documentation ...

Comment: This explains why initWithStyle was mysteriously being called as a result of doing a default init on a UITableViewController. I agree it's a bit confusing.